# Splines with differential conditions?

Tags: r, fitting, splines, restrictions

I have a set of points $(x_i,y_i)\in{\mathbb R}_+\times{\mathbb R}$, $i=1,...,n$, ($x_i$ are the independent variables and $y_i$ are the dependent variables or responses) that I want to fit using splines (I am open to any choice at the moment). So, I want to create the interpolating function $S(x):{\mathbb R}_+\rightarrow {\mathbb R}$. However, I need to restrict $S(x)$ to satisfy $\frac{d S(x)}{dx} \geq f(x)$, where $f$ is a known function. Is this possible? If so, are there any tools in R to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible, because by varying the number $a$ you could fit $x\to f(x)+a$ to the data using (say) least squares. Indeed, this idea suggests replacing your data by $(x_i, y_i-F(x_i))$ where $F^\prime=f$ and requiring the spline to be monotonically increasing: this sounds like [monotonic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=monotonic+regression), *q.v.*

Specifically, find a monotonic (increasing) spline for the data $(x_i, y_i-F(x_i))$ where $$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t.$$Suppose $T$ is such a differentiable monotonic spline for $(x_i,y_i-F(x_i))$.  This means $T^\prime$ is everywhere non-negative and that for all $i$, $T(x_i)=y_i-F(x_i)$. Then $S(x) = T(x)+F(x)$ obviously has the two properties you require of it: $$S(x_i)=T(x_i)+F(x_i) = (y_i-F(x_i)) + F(x_i)=y_i$$ for all $i$ and $$S^\prime(x) = T^\prime(x)+F^\prime(x) = T^\prime(x)+f(x) \ge f(x).$$